Bugzilla and ldap integration issue
I have local ldap with below settings.

I have bugzilla ldap config as below,
   "LDAPBaseDN" : "ou=users,dc=XXXX,dc=com",
   "LDAPbinddn" : "cn=admin,dc=XXXX,dc=com:password",
   "LDAPfilter" : "",
   "LDAPmailattribute" : "email",
   "LDAPserver" : "ldap://localhost:389",
   "LDAPstarttls" : "0",
   "LDAPuidattribute" : "uid"

But I am not able to login with the error - The login or password you entered is not valid.

This is resolved. Thanks,
